# ADFv2 SSIS-IR and DB2 Driver IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1. SSIS package Unexpected Termination in prevalidate

Tags: azure, ssis, db2, db2-luw

Using ADFv2 SSIS-IR and DB2 Driver IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1. Have defined the TCPIP Nodes and database using db2cmd DB2 CATALOG commands. Defined 32-bit and 64-bit SystemDSNs. The st.err and st.out from the SSIS-IR provisioning show all commands were successful and echos all the CATALOG and ODBC DSNs as expected. 
Everything look good but SSIS packages fail with "Unexpected Termination" in Prevalidate when specifying the configured SystemDSNs. There is not a single message in SSISDB to review.  The package is simple - one data flow task with an ODBC data source specifying the SystemDSN and a simple Rowcount task just to test the connection.
I have created a second SSIS package that dumps the event logs for the node and I see this message

```
    2018-05-11 16:32:05.0000000|The description for Event ID '1073819648' in     
Source 'SQLISPackage140' cannot be found.      
The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message,     
or you may not have permission to access them.      
The following information is part of the event:'ReadApplicationEventLogtoBlob|SQLISPackage140|Information
```

Anyone have any clues on this I am a bit stumped right now
Thanks in advance

Comment: What messages appear in the Db2-client diagnostic file? (db2diag.log)

Comment: Additionally, on the db2cmd command line, are you able to successfully connect to the Db2 database, and successfully run the same count SQL, using the same credentials you supplied for the Db2-connection in SSIS ?

Comment: Since it is an SSIS-IR node I cannot connect to the VM it is running on so I cannot get on the server and test the connection directly. I will see if I can add a way to dump the db2dial.log to somewhere I can read it - thanks for the clue as to the log name.

Comment: Also, would like to know why this was down voted. Happy to improve my question asking just give me the feedback thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created another ssis package that simply uses c# script task to try to connect to the DSN.  And am receiving a more useful message.
Script Task Error: ERROR[08001][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1336N The remote host "namehere" was not found. SQLSTATE=08001
I am looking into the connectivity to the namehere database as configured and working to identify why I connect find the server. Thank you everyone who took a look.